# How to autoload study templates in Tradingview charting library?

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I trying to load saved study templates from server like name "111" when page load in Tradingview charting library ver. 1.14, but for a few days nothing works. 
I adapted save/load templates and charts to my server, but how to load automaticaly when page load? I use standard url from charting library, just changing domain. Please help!

```
var udf_datafeed = new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("http://example.com:8888");

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function initOnReady() {
    var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
    debug: true, 
    fullscreen: true,
    symbol: 'BTCUSDT',
    interval: '1',
    container_id: "tv_chart_container",
    datafeed: udf_datafeed,
    library_path: "charting_library/charting_library/",
    locale: getParameterByName('lang') || "en",
    timezone: 'Europe/Moscow', 
    charts_storage_url: 'http://example.com',
    charts_storage_api_version: "1.1",
    client_id: 'Alantar', 
    user_id: 'Alantar', 
    theme: 'Dark', 
    });


    widget.onChartReady(function() {
        //widget.chart().applyTemplate('111');
        //widget.subscribe('load_study template', function (res, res1) {
        //      console.log("template !!!!!!!!!!" + JSON.stringify(res) + ' ,,, ' + res1);
        //});
    });

 // widget.subscribe('load_study template', '111');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initOnReady, false);

    };
```

Comment: I reply to myself, maybe someone else need like this, after a week i found how it need to made. 
`widget.onChartReady(function() { 
var templ = JSON.parse('TEMPLATE_FROM_DB');
widget.chart().applyStudyTemplate(templ);
});`